# I alone describe many things

Tags: riddle, word, letters

> I alone describe many things.
>   Add a letter and I become the perfect fit.
>   Add one more and I've hurt many.
>   Drop a letter to make me all natural.

*What am I talking about?*

Comment: My solution fits great. I'm hoping I made it so nobody can figure out false ones.

Comment: With only four lines, it's a virtual guarantee that someone will find a false fit.  Most of them aren't really "fits", though; they're "stretches".

Comment: My solution IS a fit!

Comment: drop a letter from the original word or the one you have formed?

Comment: Formed. Sorry if that wasn't clearp

Comment: Clear* ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is:

> I

I alone describe many things.

> "I" describe many things on a daily basis.

Add a letter and I become the perfect fit.

> It, It could be anything so it is fit.

Add one more and I've hurt many.

> Fit, not being fit has hurt many.

Drop a letter to make me all natural.

> It, again it could be anything so it is natural.

Comment: Way to go! :D ${}$

Comment: I got as far as the first two lines, but the last two don't fit that well :-( @warspy

Comment: @rand al'thor Well my solution wasn't as great as this one. It was "it", "fit", "fist", "fst"..

Comment: I'll probably make another, a better one, later.

Comment: @rand al'thor http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/i-am-used-to-keep-people-out

Comment: @warspyking please explain how this answer (which matches zero of your expected answer) is accepted, and another answer (which matches two of your expected answer) is not.

Comment: @Ian MacDonald I had already said that answer was wrong, and I don't turn back on things I say.

Answer (score 3):

Congrats @user! Aw, I was thinking of the first word but didn't figure out how some of the lines would fit.

Thanks for the exercise @warspyking. I like how the previous line almost alluded to the next word.

Now that the actual answer is out, here is another stretch for fun.

I alone describe many things.

> **ink**
> One can write out the descriptions of many things with a pen or other ink-filled writing instrument.

Add a letter and I become the perfect fit.

> **link**
> Things that link fit well together.

Add one more and I've hurt many.

> **plink**
> As a verb meaning “to shoot", to plink at someone is likely to hurt that person.

Drop a letter to make me all natural.

> **pink**
> A colour found in nature or the colour of a ruddy person in his all natural birthday suit.

Comment: I lol'ed at pink. Technically pink isn't even a real color. It's an illusion. I wouldn't call it natural :D

Answer (score 2):

I alone describe many things.

> **It**
>  You can indicate almost anything with "it".

Add a letter and I become the perfect fit.

> **F**it
>  I don't know how much more perfect "fit" you can get.

Add one more and I've hurt many.

> Fi**a**t
>  Cars are dangerous.

Drop a letter to make me all natural.

> Fat
>  Mammals all have fat naturally.

---

Here's a couple more that are more of a stretch.

I alone describe many things.

> **Kin**
>  Everyone is someone's relative.

Add a letter and I become the perfect fit.

> **A**kin
>  When you're a good match, you might be akin to the perfect solution.

Add one more and I've hurt many.

> A**s**kin
>  It's dangerous to be askin too many questions.

Drop a letter to make me all natural.

> Skin
>  It's pretty natural.

---

I alone describe many things.

> **Hard**
>  Many things are difficult.

Add a letter and I become the perfect fit.

> **S**hard
>  A shard of glass is like a puzzle piece for a broken window.

Add one more and I've hurt many.

> Shar**e**d
>  Be careful about the gossip you share.

Drop a letter to make me all natural.

> Shred
>  Animals naturally shred their food.

Comment: Nope ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: That's actually quite clever. I like the "cars are dangerous.".

Comment: This was actually a good answer. But wrong.

Comment: None of these are correct. Your first guess was close.

Answer (score 1):

The word is:

> RAM

Alone I describe many things:

> Ram could be a model of car or an animal or a battering device.

Add a letter and I become te perfect fit:

> CRAM, adding a letter and getting a tight fit.

Add another and I have hurt many:

> CRAMP, adding a letter and getting something that has probably hurt everyone at some point (but don't buy into that nonsense about eating+swimming).

Drop a letter and I become all natural:

> CAMP, remove the R and get a nature-based activity.

Comment: The other answer was closer, but I like this noneoftheless