# I am used to keep people out

Tags: riddle, english

> I am used to keep people out
>   Divide me in half to gain access
>   Replace access's end to discover your history
>   Replace history's beginning to meet your end

*What is it I am talking about?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> password

Keeps people out

> pass

Let's you in

> past

Is your history

> last

Is your end

Comment: Good job! These are becoming fun!

Answer (score 4):

I am used to keep people out:

> gates

Divide me in half to gain access:

> gat (a revolver or pistol; possibly also a reference to how said gates are opened)

Replace access's end to discover your history:

> gad (meaning to go around from one place to another, in the pursuit of pleasure or entertainment)

Replace history's beginning to meet your end:

> sad (deaths are sad)

Comment: This answer was biased to your last name lol.

Comment: Yes. Yes it was. It was worth a shot. :P @warspyking

Comment: I liked the answer, but I never knew gad was a word!